# macOS Screen Saver Keyboard Interaction

Tags: macos, nsview, screensaver

I've made a custom macOS Screen Saver (from the Xcode template). It installs and works fine, except when I want to dismiss the Screen Saver. I can only dismiss it when I press a keyboard modifier key like Ctrl, no standard keys like spacebar, etc.

I have a niggling feeling that the NSView which is displaying my content is swallowing up the standard key events and therefore not dismissing the Screen Saver. Does anyone have any ideas to resolve this?

Comment: Please post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @Willeke are you serious? I just need some help ignoring keyboard events.

Comment: You might find the cause of the issue when you're creating the mcve. If you don't want to create a mcve then tell us how to reproduce the issue. Do other screen savers stop on key events?

Answer (score 1):

I figured out what was going on. I had a `SceneKit` view which was doing nothing with the key events. The solution was to manually pass it up to the superview which is in fact the `ScreenSaverView`.

```
- (void)keyDown:(NSEvent *)event
{
    [self.view.superview keyDown:event];
}

- (void)keyUp:(NSEvent *)event
{
    [self.view.superview keyUp:event];
}
```